# How do I make variables accessible everywhere?

Tags: java, swing

I am using java swing and I have tried using new text as a parameter but I am not sure how, there is also the fact that I have "});" which is completely messed up but it works, and i tried fixing it and it doesn't work

this code is inside my main

```
public String newText = "";

a.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    JFrame popup = new JFrame("Choose...");
    popup.setSize(250,250);
    popup.setLayout(null);
    popup.setVisible(true);
    JButton o=new JButton("o");
    o.setBounds(25,75,100,100); 
    popup.add(o);
    o.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae, String newText){
        newText = "O";
      }
    });
    JButton x=new JButton("x"); 
    x.setBounds(125,75,100,100);  
    popup.add(x);
    if (!newText.equals(""))
        a.setText(newText);
  }
});
```

Comment: You cannot put `public String` inside of main. What is `a`? 1) Please show the full class 2) What exactly isn't working and what variable are you trying to access?

Comment: Please include some explanation about what you wanted to happen and in what way it doesn't work (e.g. I want it do do X, but Y happens instead).

Comment: You can use static variable to achieve that. Declare your `newText` variable by `public static String newText = ""`. But by doing this, `newText` will be common for each instances of your class

Comment: Thank you for the help, it is my first time using stackoverflow. I have a link to it https://replit.com/@JavaScriptGod/JavaSwing#Main.java

Comment: `newText = "O";` modifies only the argument (=local variable) of actionPerformed, this will have no effect on the outside world. It would probably be a good idea to not have multiple variables called newText...

Comment: @Hpn4 that worked, thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have tried using `newText` as a parameter

Here?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae, String newText){
```

This is not valid code. `ActionListener` is  an interface; an interface is a contract that must be followed. You cannot  simply add variables to  existing method  signatures.

Assuming you wanted to modify the button text, you could do this

```
public class Main {

    public String newText;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       new Main().run();
    }

    public void run() {

        System.out.printf("before: newText = %s%n", newText);
        final JButton o = new JButton("o");
        // ...
        o.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                Main.this.newText = "O"; // Sets the field
                System.out.printf("action: newText = %s%n", Main.this.newText);
                o.setText(Main.this.newText);
            }
        });
        System.out.printf("actionListener set : newText = %s%n", newText);
    }
}
```

However, trying to use `newText.equals` outside of the action listener happens on a different thread, meaning the code does not run "top to bottom". E.g. the variable isn't "set" in the execution order that the code reads as. Added print statements to show this